# This seems like a bug in .NET's JavaScript deserialize... is it?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

Basically, I found that a JSON string that is a JavaScript object (associative array) with an empty string for one of its properties/keys will cause the built in .NET Serializer to throw an exception.

For example this code:

```
string json = "{ \"\" : [\"b\"] }";

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var map = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
```

Will throw an ArgumentException, suggesting that maybe proper JSON doesn’t allow empty strings for property names.  Just glancing at the [Backaus Naur Form Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) / [Syntax Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) on [Crockford’s](http://json.org/) site suggests that an empty string is allowed.

```
object => '{'  string ':' value '}'
string => ""
       => " chars "
```

Comment: I switched my code over to JSON.NET a few weeks ago and found it to be much better..  Maybe worth a shot if it's an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. That sure looks like a bug to me. This is definitely valid:

```
var x = {"" : ["b"]}
alert(x[""]);
```

I'm not saying you *should* do this, but you *can* do it in JS.

*Edit* Having said that. Your code works for me. What version of .NET are you using?

*Edit* Confirmed. It breaks in .NET 3.5 but works in 4.0.

Comment: I'm using v3.5... are you using 4.0/4.5?